# Sort one list based on other

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, arraylist, ip-address

I have below two list:

```
list_ip = [10.100.1.100, 10.100.1.30, 10.100.1.110, 10.100.1.40]
list_host = [host1, host2, host3, host4]
```

What I need is to get the `list_host` sorted based on the ip address sorting on `list_ip`.

Expected output:

```
[host2, host4, host1, host3]
```

How do I start? Which function could I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sorting you can zip the 2 list together, with the key as 1st element in the tuples, then print the 2nd elements from the sorted result

if you only work with 10.100.1.x then you just need to extract x(by split & int conversion) as key. If you are dealing with many different subnets, yes you need to convert to ipaddress.IPV4Address objects which are naturally ordered by numeric value instead of string representations.

```
print([y[1] for y in sorted(zip([int(x.split('.')[-1]) for x in list_ip],list_host))])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to write the sorted functio  with python  ipaddress package ?